# shell_exec not displaying anything PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a new install of Ubuntu Server 12. What I'm trying to do is execute the landscape-info command on a php webpage residing on the server so I can use the data returned but it won't run for some reason. I've checked apache works as I can see webpages from the servers IP address and checked safe mode is turned off using phpinfo() but it still fails to display anything. I've never ran apache myself and have little linux experience. Any ideas what could be causing this or what to check? Thanks.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('../../usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo');
echo "$output";
?>
```

edit:

changed to :

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo');
echo $output;
?>
```

looking in apache error.log I've found a lot of :

```
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.landscape'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo", line 22, in <module>
    run(sys.argv[1:], reactor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/deployment.py", line 96, in run
    setup_logging()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/deployment.py", line 83, in setup_logging
    os.mkdir(landscape_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/deployment.py", line 83, in setup_logging
    os.mkdir(landscape_dir)
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your logs?

Comment: *This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required.* You might want to validate if the output of the executable is valid. It can also occur that an executable acts differently in the PHP-shell.

Comment: i'' bet on user permission issue

Comment: Using relative paths like that is generally a pretty bad idea as "current directory" can be a bit unpredictable (you can use [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd) to check what it currently is). Use an absolute path (starting with `/`), based on `__DIR__` / `dirname(__FILE__)` if you need it to move when your script does.

Comment: Might also be handy to resolve the absolute path where you need to be. It's way safer than traverse up/down from your current position. When you move your code it will instantly break.

Comment: On an unrelated code-style point: `echo "$output";` is 100% guaranteed to be the same as `echo $output;` but with more typing for you and more processing for the compiler.

Comment: Updated OP. Looking at that I'm guessing I haven't got some permissions set that I require. Once again, I don't really have a clue how to do about fixing this? Also cheers, I've set an absolute path and removed the quotes from the $output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the directory /var/www/.landscape does not exists or is not writable. Run this in the terminal:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/.landscape && chmod -R og+rwX /var/www/.landscape
```

That will make the required directory with no error if it already exists and then will change its permissions, recursively, to be readable/writable for everyone, and if it has any sub-directories they'll be accessible as well..

Comment: I just get this when I try that: 
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/.landscape': Operation not permitted

Comment: Try running chmod as root user from the command line: `sudo chmod -R og+rwX /var/www/.landscape`